# What happened to the Enterprise-E?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise, star-trek-picard

*Star Trek: Picard* Season 3 rather notably never showed the Enterprise-E. There was a line tossed in as to why, but it seemed to imply the audience should know the reference.

> GEORDI: And obviously, we can't use the Enterprise-E.
> WORF: That was not my fault!

What happened to the ship?

Comment: Sounds like a noodle incident to me.

Comment: @DavidW For the purposes of dialogue, it was totally a noodle incident. But it seems odd to dismiss a ship that was in 3 movies in such a way.

Comment: Tangentially related: [What happened to the Enterprise-F?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/275023/16845)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It's not clear.** Exactly how unclear depends on what you count as canon.

The latest the ship is seen on-screen is in 2384, during the *Star Trek: Prodigy* episode "Supernova, Part 2", where it's badly damaged. Picard stepped down in 2381 so Worf may have been in command. A ship is seen with the Enterprise's registry number on its nacelles but some shots clearly intend it to be the USS Sovereign, so which ship is which and what eventually happens to the Enterprise is debatable.

Off-screen, the fate of the ship is hinted at in *Star Trek: Picard Logs*, a series of posts on Instagram that give some background on the ships and characters involved in the series. [See Memory Alpha for transcripts of the videos](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Picard_Logs).

- [The entry about Worf](https://www.instagram.com/p/Coh8GassSsb/) lists him as a former captain of the Enterprise E, stating that his time in the role was brief and that he stepped down after "the incident above Kriilar Prime".
- [The entry about the various Enterprises](https://www.instagram.com/p/Coh6YkJNuJk/) states that the E's final mission was classified and doesn't say if this final mission was the same thing as "the incident above Kriilar Prime".

Given that the battle in *Prodigy* is clearly not Worf's fault (and would be a rather tasteless thing to joke about), the characters are presumably referring to whatever happened on that final mission. However, exactly what that is has deliberately been left ambiguous.