# What happened to the Enterprise-F?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise, star-trek-picard

The ship gets a whopping 30 seconds of screen time (if that) in *Picard* Season 3 before events take over. Major spoilers for Season 3 ahead

> The ship is shown leaving Space Dock for Frontier Day. Admiral Shelby is in the command chair until the Borg take over the younger crew and apparently kill her. At the end of the episode, the Titan-A has been re-christened to Enterprise-G. Was the Enterprise-F destroyed? Decommissioned? Rechristened?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNlp9.png Out of commission by 2387, apparently.

Comment: She makes *Admiral*?  Starfleet must be officer-poor.

Comment: @MarcWilson In case you forgot, she was more ambitious about her career than Will Riker.

Comment: @MarcWilson - She was already borderline evil. That's the only qualification required to become a Starfleet Admiral

Comment: Tangentially related: [What happened to the Enterprise-E?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/275022/16845)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She was decommissioned, as was apparently already planned (in universe) from the beginning of season 3.

From [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-F)):

> In 2401, the ship was slated for early decommissioning around the same time as the terrorist attack in District Seven on M'talas Prime. (PIC: "The Next Generation")

That entry provides two image sources from [different](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/2/26/USS-Enterprise-F.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20230216135506&path-prefix=en) [episodes](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/7/7b/Picard_and_Riker_access_files.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20230318125009&path-prefix=en), and I'll include the clearest here:

[image: Image of the Enterprise-F marked "slated for early decommission"]

So it would appear that - for whatever reason - the ship was already on her way to retirement, and her appearance was a last hurrah, after which her decommissioning proceeded as planned. Valorum's comment provides a source [offering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNlp9.png) "critical systems were compromised during 'the Monfette Gambit'" as the reason for her short service duration. That image appears to come from [an official Instagram](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Monfette_Gambit) presenting supplementary information for the season.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was not certainly destroyed. The only ship firing on the fleet was Titan and she could not have totally destroyed the Enterprise-F.

There is no apparent reason for decommissioning it, either. At least nothing that was mentioned on the show.

They rechristened Titan to Ent-G. That indicate that the Ent-F could not be  rechristened.

One theory could be that since Picard saved humanity (again,) and he was commanding Titan at the time, the Titan has to carry the Enterprise legacy.  Decomission and put the Ent-F in fleet museum and let Titan continue the legacy of Enterprise with Ent-F.

Does that mean we can expect another Picard season? I don't know.

Comment: Imagine the nu-trekkies brains exploding if the Enterprise-D had been recommissioned as the Enterprise-G.  I think the point is there is zero logic to retiring a starship that ought to have a 100 year service lifetime.

Comment: Just drop a line somewhere mentioning what happened to E and F. Just like they confirmed that E was destroyed while Worf was commanding it - in one sentence and one look on Worf's face - "It wasn't my fault". I love that.